# `NSUserDefaults` not saving float properly

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, nsuserdefaults

I am building an application in which I want to save some user data by using `NSUserDefaults`, and it is a property of one of my controllers as following:

```
  @property (nonatomic, strong) NSUserDefaults *userPreference;
  @synthesize userPreference = _userPreference;
```

And I am trying to save something called a `scale` that should be a float, so I do something like this in the getter to put in some default values of `scale` in case user did not enter one:

```
  if (!_userPreference) {
      _userPreference = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
  }

  if (![_userPreference floatForKey:@"scale"]) { 
      // if user has not entered this info yet
      // also 0 is not a valid value so I can do this
      [_userPreference setFloat:100.0 forKey:@"scale"]; // let default scale be 100.0
      [_userPreference synchronize];
  }
```

However, when I later on query this, no matter what I set in the default value, the following command:

```
  [self.userPreference floatForKey:@"scale"];
```

always `return 1`. I am not sure what is happening. Am I not creating the `NSUserDefaults` correctly?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: @VenkatManoharPerepa setFloat: expects a float value and not a NSString.

Comment: 1.Are you modifiying Your value after getting it ?? 2. and further try to create separate NSUSERDefaults object for Retrieving and Storing let's  see. in case if you using separate functions for getting and setting values if not delete your application from simulator and clean it and rebuild it.

Comment: @Durgaprasad We know 100.0 is float! the previous comment to which 
Amar was pointing out has been deleted!

Comment: Did you set it to 1 at some point? Once you've set it, the if clause will never evaluate to True again unless you go manually delete the user defaults for this app.

Comment: @rdelmar hmm that might be the case! I will investigate.

Comment: @rdelmar I don't think that's the case though. Since I just tried replacing the NSUserDefaults with NSMutableDictionary and it worked out fine. The value got saved properly.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by that. Just try deleting the "!" in your if clause. Run it once, put the "!" back and then retrieve the default and see if it changes to 100.

Comment: @rdelmar Ha! that worked!!! Could it be that the default value for a number in `NSUserDefautlts` is `1`?

Comment: I don't think so. Are you sure you didn't use 1 the first time you tested it?

Comment: @rdelmar I might have... Yeah I have to keep in mind that these data are persistent on the disk. Thank you so much for your help! You've helped me with 2 problems tonight already!

Answer (score 3):

Store using

```
   [_userPreference setObject:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:100.0] forKey:@"Scale"];
   [_userPreference synchronize];
```

and retrieve it using

```
   float value = [[_userPreference objectForKey:@"Scale"] floatValue];
```

Answer (score 3):

if you want to use NSUserDefaults, do not create any variables or @propertys. Just use

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setFloat:forKey:]
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
```

to save your data and

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] floatForKey:]
```

for fetching data.

Comment: @Enzo You can also verify if the value is getting stored by looking for `KL.appname.plist` file @ location `/Users/<username>/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/<ios_version>/Applications/<appid>/Library/Preferences`. This plist will contain key and corresponding value.

Comment: @Valentin Shamardin I tried this and I did find the plist file. But even in the plist file the value for `scale` is still `1` for some reason. So it didn't really work.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried this to set the float value:

```
[_userPreference setObject:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:100.0f] forKey@"scale"];
```

and the following to retrieve:

```
CGFloat scale = [[_userPreference objectForKey@"scale"] floatValue];
```

Comment: I have tried this as well, and that also returns 1 for some reason. For the same thing NSDictionary works as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Change your `if` condition to this:

```
if ([_userPreference floatForKey:@"scale"] == 0.0f ) {
```

NSUserDefaults will always return 0.0f if no value is set for the key. Since you are saying that "also 0 is not a valid", you can safely use this approach

Answer (score -1):

try this

```
 -(void) saveFloatToUserDefaults:(float)x forKey:(NSString *)key {
     NSUserDefaults * userDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
     [userDefaults setFloat:x forKey:key];
     [userDefaults synchronize];
 }

 -(float) retriveFromUserDefaultsForKey:(NSString *)key {
     NSUserDefaults * userDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
     return [userDefaults floatForKey:key];
 }

 [self saveFloatToUserDefaults:6.55 forKey:@"myFloat"];
 float x = [self retriveFromUserDefaultsForKey:@"myFloat"];
```

Comment: How is this different from the existing methods on NSUserDefaults except for the generally unnecessary call to -synchronize? All you're doing is renaming them... with a typo.

Comment: both function are global and you can use it any where in you project. just call the function